# Read text field values from a source page and populate corresponding fileds in offline web page using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

instead of clicking view->source can i invoke this action using jquery. If yes, how can i iterate over the fileds present in the source and get all the values of input, select and checkbox tags and display through alert? Please provide a sample of this implementation.
Im working with IE and Firefox browsers.

Jquery and html looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#save').click(function(){
window.location="view-source:" + window.location.href;
var o = {};
var $inputs  = $('form input,form select');
$inputs.forEach(function(i,v){
var $input = $(v);
o[$input.attr('id')] = $input.val();
});
alert("the values are "+o);
});
});

<form id="formname">
<input class="inputbox" id="startdate" name="change_request.start_date" type="text" value="09-07-2013 16:37:58"/>
<input class="inputbox" id="enddate" name="change_request.end_date" type="text" value="09-08-2013 06:37:58" />
<input class="submitbutton" id="save" type="submit" value="Save">
```

Pls bear with me as I'm experimenting with jquery and im new to it.

Comment: instead of clicking view->source can i invoke this action using jquery. If yes, how can i iterate over the fileds present in the source and get all the values of input, select and checkbox tags and display through alert?

Answer (score 2):

that is not possible.. ever document inside a browser runs in a diff context. so the script on your file system would never be able to access the document running from the server.

what instead you can do is write two scripts.
1.will read values and will present to you those in a serialized fashion on the browser console.
2.A script that will de-searialize the contents on the local web page and then populate the controls with the data

Suppose you have 2 controls like

then in the first script you can use - this will hve to be injected in the web page running from server

```
var o = {};
o.one = $('#one').val();
o.two = $('#two').val();
console.log(JSON.stringify(o));
```

:-now you have the json of the object on your console

in the second script - that you will have to inject in the page on the file system

```
var o = JSON.parse(o);
$('#one').val(o.one);
$('#two').val(o.two);
```

also you can loop through all the elements using proper constructs like

```
var o = {};
var $inputs  = $('form input,form select');
$inputs.forEach(function(i,v){
 var $input = $(v);
 o[$input.attr('id')] = $input.val();
});
```

just makr sure you have id for all the controls or you can use name `$(/*selector*/).attr('name')`

Comment: could u please explain this with a simple example?

Comment: also if the web page is not using auth and stuff like that. the second answer by @elfentech is also viable

Comment: i guess this would not be feasible to implement... However, is there a way where i can loop and pick all the values corresponding to each of the html input,select tags and checkboxes present in the view source page of the web form and utilise those to populate the fields of my offline page?

Comment: yes surely you can loop thru all the inputs

Comment: i just edited my question... i could think of some implementation in this way..

Comment: i have added the code in ques. i'm actually trying to open the view source and read the values. The above code for view source would work in firefox and chrome but not in IE. i would want the code for IE. Also opening of voew source, reading values and populating values has to happen as a background activity on a button click.

Answer (score 0):

There no way you can do this, since JQuery can read only a web page, not a webpage set on another tab/browser page.

A solution would have been to do that in Ajax, but this solution is not possible:

> basic jQuery ajax overview

To dynamically load content in a website with Ajax, you have three basic options:

```
.load()
```

Load a webpage from your server, and place the output into an element on the page.

```
.get() and .post()
```

Load a webpage from your server, and decide what to do with the output. Additionally, you have the option to pass variables.

```
.ajax()
```

Load a webpage from your server, and decide what to do with the output. Additionally, you have several advanced options.